# How do I download and play an audio from Firebase Storage in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have 2 buttons,download and play
when i click the download button it should download the mp3 file that i already uploaded on FireBase storage.

and when i click the play button it should play the downloaded audio.

I looked into some tutorials but no success.
The code is not showing any error but not downloading the audio file either.

Please help and provide a very simple solution,this is very important.

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    StorageReference storageReference,ref;
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    Button down;;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        down=findViewById(R.id.down);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);


        down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                download();
            }
        });
    }





    public void download(){
        storageReference=firebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        ref=storageReference.child("testaudio.mp3");
        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) { String url = uri.toString();
               downloadFiles(MainActivity.this,"testaudiofile",".mp3",DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,url);
            //    downloadFile();

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });

    }


    public void downloadFiles(Context context,String fileName,String fileExtension,String destinationDirectory,String url) {

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,destinationDirectory,fileName+fileExtension);
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);

    }



public void Play(){

}




}
```

```html
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:text="Download"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play"
        android:onClick="Play"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In the play method first get the path of mp3 file and pass it to mp3 object and play .Hope it will help.

Comment: first please give me the code to download the file....playing it will come later